# efficient way to load contacts with name and phone and picture with only one query

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite, android-contentprovider, android-contacts

I have the following code to load all contacts with their phones and pictures on samsung s3 device.

```
public static void getAllContactWithNumberAndNameAndPhoto(Context context,
            ArrayList<ContactInfo> mContactList, boolean starred) {

        ContentResolver cr = context.getContentResolver();

        Cursor cur = null;
        if (starred == true) {
            cur = cr.query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, null,
                    "starred=?", new String[] { "1" }, null);
        } else {

            cur = cr.query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, null, null,
                    null, null);
        }
        if (cur.getCount() > 0) {
            while (cur.moveToNext()) {

                ContactInfo item = new ContactInfo();
                String id = cur.getString(cur
                        .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));
                String name = cur
                        .getString(cur
                                .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));
                // Uri photo = PhoneUtils.getPhotoUriFromID(context, id);
                String starredValue = cur.getString(cur
                        .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.STARRED));
                boolean isFav = false;
                if (starredValue.equals("1"))
                    isFav = true;

                if (Integer
                        .parseInt(cur.getString(cur
                                .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER))) > 0) {
                    Cursor pCur = cr.query(
                            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI,
                            null,
                            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID
                                    + " = ?", new String[] { id }, null);
                    while (pCur.moveToNext()) {

                        String phoneNo = pCur
                                .getString(pCur
                                        .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
                        item.addPhone(removeCharactersFromPhoneNumber(phoneNo));
                    }
                    pCur.close();

                    // if (photo != null) {
                    //
                    // item.setPhoto(photo.toString());
                    // }

                    item.setName(name);
                    item.setFavorite(isFav);
                    item.setRecent(false);

                    mContactList.add(item);
                }
            }
            cur.close();
        }
    }
```

when I run this code on 1000 contacts it takes about 40 second to load
when I remove the part of loading multiple phones for the same 1000 contact, it takes about 1.5 second.

Can any one tell me if there is an efficient way to load contacts phone and not let the user to wait all this time.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
private Cursor getContacts() {
    // Run query
    Uri uri = ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI;
    String[] projection = new String[] { ContactsContract.Contacts._ID,
        ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME, ContactsContract.Contacts.PHOTO_URI, ContactsContract.Contacts.PHOTO_THUMBNAIL_URI, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI }; // put the items u need here
    String selection = ContactsContract.Contacts.IN_VISIBLE_GROUP + " = '"
        + ("1") + "'";
    String[] selectionArgs = null;
    String sortOrder = ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME
        + " COLLATE LOCALIZED ASC";
    return getContentResolver().query(uri, projection, selection, selectionArgs,
        sortOrder);
  }
```

Comment: ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI is not a field inside ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI and this is make illegalargumentexception (invalid column content)